# Organization name doesn't change after importing - CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a .bak file with all my customizations and common data for different organizations, created from organization called 'DevOrg'

**I bring it to another environment**, I create a TestOrg_MSCRM, restore it with the backup, and with the Deployment Manager import the org 'TestOrg'

If I query the Organization table for 'TestOrg', it has the same **ID** and **name** than 'DevOrg'

However, when I create SecondOrg_MSCRM and do the same process, the ID and Name changes in the step of the Deployment Manager.

Both instances are working correctly, however having the incorrect name for the org causes connection problems when using the web portal.

I'm wondering at first time doesn't change the ID and Name because are unique, but;

1.Is there anyway to change it while importing, and not having to change it manually in DB?

2.Are there any other tables with this kind of information for keep on mind?

Comment: Are the source and target system the same?

Comment: Yes, both are CRM 2011, same SQL Server version, ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a bit to do but thankfully [someone has dealt with it already](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdeployment/thread/b8dfb946-bb02-4fb9-a92f-22ffb8b7071c).  I haven't tried it myself so can't vouch for it but it's getting good feedback.  I have the SQL in my back pocket for when I do need it.

Comment: Thanks for post! It help me check which tables I should double check, but as OrganizationId is not a problem for me I haven't run anything, just change org and business unit name in DB, and for the second import it changes automatically by CRM Deployment Manager.